# Installing an OS from source on separate partition. Is this possible?

Tags: centos, partition, system-installation

I'm trying to install Minimal CentOS on a small partition and the installer quits and brings me to a prompt every time. It says something like it can't find initrd.img.

I was wondering if I could install and set it up in a separate partition from within my host OS?

host is Debian

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Are you trying to install CentOS _from within Debian_? What do you mean by "from source"? Are you building CentOS from source code?

Comment: Yes I meant from within Debian. I edited the question. Is it more clear?